# pyEX Chart Batch Request (IEX Cloud API)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to use `pyEX` to get the closing prices of a list of tickers and then convert that into a pandas data frame. I want the range of prices to be a year in length. Based on the documentation I should assign a value of `'1y'` to the `range_` parameter. However when I do this only get two weeks of data. The following code returns a data frame of 50 rows (10 for each stock) meaning 10 unique days of prices.

```py
import pandas as pd
import pyEX as p

tickers = ['AAPL', 'FB', 'AMZN', 'GOOGL', 'NFLX']
c = p.Client(api_token='YOUR_TOKEN_HERE', version='sandbox')
pd.DataFrame(c.batchDF(symbols=tickers, fields='chart', range_='1y')['chart'])
```

I have tried changing the range variable to a value below 2 weeks, like 5 days (`'5d'`) and that works however it seems not return anything longer than two weeks even if `range_` is greater than two weeks. I'm wondering if anybody else has run into this problem or figured out a workaround?

Here is a link to the documentation: https://pyex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pyEX/stocks/batch.html?highlight=batch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the pyEX [documentation](https://pyex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apisrc/stocks.html), the batchDF call defaults the parameter 'last' to 10.

Provide the 'last' parameter, as shown here, to get the full year of data:

```
c.batchDF(symbols=tickers, fields='chart', last=365, range_='1y')
```

The full example looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyEX as p

tickers = ['AAPL', 'FB', 'AMZN', 'GOOGL', 'NFLX']
c = p.Client(api_token='YOUR_TOKEN_HERE', version='sandbox')
pd.DataFrame(c.batchDF(symbols=tickers, fields='chart', last=365, range_='1y')['chart'])
```